# Import a Datalog knowledge base in Racket

Tags: import, racket, datalog

Is it possible in Datalog Racket to import and use a knowledge base defined in a file x declared as "#lang datalog" into another file y declared as "#lang racket"?

ex:

```
;; x.rkt

#lang datalog

parent(john, douglas).


;; y.rkt

#lang racket

(require datalog)

(require "x.rkt")

;;(datalog parent (? (X douglas)))  DOES NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exported theory from `#lang datalog` is always named `theory`, so your `y.rkt` should be:

```
#lang racket

(require datalog
         "x.rkt")

(datalog theory (? (parent X douglas)))
```

Note that we are querying the `parent` table, so we need to specify it as `(? (parent X douglas))`. `(? (X douglas))` is incorrect.

Lastly, if you wish to rename the exported theory from `x.rkt`, you can use `rename-in`:

```
#lang racket

(require datalog
         (rename-in "x.rkt" [theory my-thy]))

(datalog my-thy (? (parent X douglas)))
```